Is there a way to access a variable in a thread-safe way with nothrow guarantee when std::atomic is not an option?
Let's say I have a class like this that can copy a value without throwing:
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
requires std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible_v<T>
      && std::is_nothrow_copy_assignable_v<T>
class ValueCopier
{
public:
    // Constructor
    ValueCopier(T const& object) noexcept
      : _object{object}
    {
        // Do nothing
    }

    // Return a copy of a stored object
    T getCopy() const noexcept
    {
        return _object;
    }

    // Change the stored object
    void setValue(T const& object) noexcept
    {
        _object = object;
    }

private:
    T _object;
};

Now the question is: is it possible to make such a class thread-safe while keeping the functions noexcept?
I can make the class thread-safe using std::atomic:
#include <atomic>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
requires std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible_v<T>
      && std::is_nothrow_copy_assignable_v<T>
class ValueCopier
{
public:
    // Constructor
    ValueCopier(T const& object) noexcept
      : _object{object}
    {
        // Do nothing
    }

    // Return a copy of a stored object
    T getCopy() const noexcept
    {
        return _object.load();
    }

    // Change the stored object
    void setValue(T const& object) noexcept
    {
        _object.store(object);
    }

private:
    std::atomic<T> _object;
};

but then I won't be able to use the class with some types since std::atomic<T> can only be used with trivially copyable types.
I can also make the class thread-safe with std::mutex:
#include <mutex>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
requires std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible_v<T>
      && std::is_nothrow_copy_assignable_v<T>
class ValueCopier
{
public:
    // Constructor
    ValueCopier(T const& object) noexcept
      : _object{object}
    {
        // Do nothing
    }

    // Return a copy of a stored object
    T getCopy() const // Not noexcept
    {
        auto const lock = std::lock_guard<std::mutex>(_mutex);
        return _object;
    }

    // Change the stored object
    void setValue(T const& object) // Not noexcept
    {
        auto const lock = std::lock_guard<std::mutex>(_mutex);
        _object = object;
    }

private:
    mutable std::mutex _mutex;
    T _object;
};

but then the functions are no longer noexcept because locking the mutex can throw.
Am I missing something? Are there maybe preconditions that when verified guarantee that locking a mutex cannot throw? Or some type other than std::mutex that would make it possible to write this?
Technically I guess a spinlock on an std::atomic<bool> would do but it seems wasteful

You need a lock free atomic<shared_ptr> , the one in the standard library uses a lock.

std::atomic<ValueCopier<T>> might be an option...

std::mutex only throws in three cases: 1) if you are doing something you shouldn't (e.g. trying to lock the same mutex multiple times from the same thread, or trying to unlock a mutex that is not locked), 2) if you have a system resource issue, and 3) if you have a bug (heap overflow etc.) that overwrote some parts of the mutex. Case 1) can easily be shown to not be relevant for your simple class, in case 3) your program is toast anyway, and I have yet to see a realistic error handling strategy for case 2) in many cases. Honestly I'd just mark your example 2 noexcept regardless of std::mutex

@chris_se (2) should not be an issue for this program, in POSIX at least.

@AhmedAEK std::shared_ptr is not trivially copyable, so you can't use it with std::atomic
@Jarod42 If T is not trivially copyable, then ValueCopier isn't either

@Eternal C++20 ships an atomic<shared_ptr> but it uses locks, also atomic_load and atomic_store (that also accept shared_ptr since c++11) use locks , but there are other implementations out there without locks, and there are more efficient implementations without weak_ptr that are lock free

@AhmedAEK Oh ok, my bad, I had not realized there was a dedicated template specialization. That is definitely an option then

@chris_se Point #3 is just "the guarantee is waved if your code has Undefined Behaviour" which is true of everything in C++ and can be implied, leaving only 2 actual cases for a throwing mutex.

I don't see how an atomic shared_ptr helps. It doesn't synchronize access to the pointed object, it just allows the shared_ptr to be manipulated by multiple threads, such as synchronizing a reset in one thread with a comparison with nullptr on another thread.

To reword the comment above, given the encapsulation of the mutex, on a POSIX pthreads implementation, lock and unlock cannot fail. So, lock/unlock are noexcept(false) but non-throwing. Therefore, marking the functions noexcept is reasonable and truthful.

And if you want to support a more exotic platform that allows lock/unlock to throw, then you have to find a way to communicate that. e.g. std::optional getCopy() const noexcept (return nullopt if lock fails, or previous unlock failed) and bool setValue(const T&) noexcept (return false if lock fails or previous unlock failed). If a previous unlock failed, you can't do much with the object so it is "poisoned" and unusable. Which is a lot of ceremony for a situation that shouldn't happen.

@JeffGarrett Replacing exceptions by error codes technically means noexcept but my question is more about how you can write a function that is guaranteed not to fail

Within standard C++, you can use std::atomic_flag which is guaranteed to be lock-free and has noexcept operations. cppreference even has an example mutex.

I think you need to make a distinction between std::mutex::lock() not being marked noexcept because it technically can fail, and whether it will actually fail in your case.
Let's first discuss in which conditions std::mutex::lock() and std::mutex::unlock() can actually fail.
Linux (glibc + GCC's libstdc++6)
On Linux GCC's libstdc++6 calls pthread_mutex_lock() and pthread_mutex_unlock() and throws an exception if these fail. First of all, let's check what types of mutexes glibc supports:

timed mutexes
recursive mutexes
error-checking mutexes
adaptive mutexes

std::mutex uses PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER to initialize the mutex, which defaults to a timed mutex.
With this in mind, glibc on Linux the pthread_mutex_lock() and pthread_mutex_unlock() can fail in the following circumstances:
pthread_mutex_lock() failures on Linux

EAGAIN if the mutex is a recursive mutex and the lock count (unsigned int in glibc source, so 32bit on Linux) has wrapped around. Since std::mutex is not a recursive mutex, this will not happen.
EDEADLK if the mutex is an error-checking mutex and a deadlock is detectd. Since std::mutex is not an error-checking mutex, this will not happen.
EOWNERDEAD if the mutex was locked by a thread that no longer exists. Unless you force-exit the current thread in the assingment operator of the wrapped type T (but just the thread, without killing the program), this will never happen with your example implementation class.
ENOTRECOVERABLE if the mutex is considered 'unrecoverable' (which can only occur once pthread_mutex_unlock() has returned ENOTRECOVERABLE for the same mutex at least once). Since std::mutex is not a recursive mutex, this will not happen.
EINVAL if the mutex was not initialized correctly. Since you use std::mutex this will not happen.
EINVAL if the mutex was created with PTHREAD_PRIO_PROTECT and the current thread's priority is higher than the specified priority ceiling. Since std::mutex does not do that this will not happen.

(See the source code for pthread_mutex_lock for details.)
pthread_mutex_unlock() failures on Linux

EPERM if you try to unlock a recursive mutex of which you are not the current owner. Since std::mutex is not a recursive, this will not happen.
ENOTRECOVERABLE if a recursive mutex was locked by a thread that has since died while holding the lock and pthread_mutex_unlock() is called by another thread. Since std::mutex is not a recursive, this will not happen.
EINVAL if the mutex was not initialized correctly. Since you use std::mutex this will not happen.

(See the source code for pthread_mutex_unlock for details.)
macOS (Apple's libc + Apple-clang's libc++)
Apple's clang/libc++ implementation also calls pthread_mutex_lock() and pthread_mutex_unlock() on macOS. Let's look at the manual to see when these can fail:
pthread_mutex_lock() failures on macOS

EINVAL if the mutex was not properly initialized. Since you use std::mutex this will not happen.
EDEADLK if a deadlock would otherwise occur. Deadlocks with mutexes can only occur if the order in which multiple mutexes are locked is not the same. Unless the copy assignment operator / copy constructor of your wrapped type T locks another global mutex (which it should never do), this will not happen.

pthread_mutex_unlock() failures on macOS

EINVAL if the mutex was not properly initialized. Since you use std::mutex this will not happen.
EPERM if the mutex was not locked by the current thread. Since your use of std::mutex only unlocks it when the same thread locked it, this will not happen.

Windows (MSVC + Microsoft's STL)
Microsoft's STL uses its own implementation of std::mutex, which uses WinAPI's AcquireSRWLockExclusive() and ReleaseSRWLockExclusive() with some additional checks.
(The source code to #include mutex and mutex.cpp are of interest here.)
Let's see in what way Microsoft's STL can fail for locking/unlocking:
std::mutex::lock() failures on Microsoft's STL

_Throw_Cpp_error(_RESOURCE_DEADLOCK_WOULD_OCCUR) if mtx_do_lock() doesn't succeed; but for a std::mutex that can only fail if you try to lock the same mutex multiple times (and the mutex is not recursive). Your codes never does that, so this will not happen.
_Throw_Cpp_error(_RESOURCE_UNAVAILABLE_TRY_AGAIN) if you attempt to lock a recursive mutex and the lock count has wrapped around. Since std::mutex is not recursive, this will not happen.

std::mutex::unlock() failures on Microsoft's STL
Microsoft's STL marks std::mutex::unlock() as noexcept to indicate it can never fail, and the code is written indeed in such a manner that that's true.
Windows (MinGW + GCC's libstdc++6)
MinGW on Windows has two different threading implementations that you can choose, winpthreads and mcfgthread. With winpthreads GCC's libstdc++6 will use pthread_mutex_lock() and pthread_mutex_unlock(), while mcfgthread tries to call Windows kernel functions directly.
Let's look at the various failure modes:
pthread_mutex_lock() failures with winpthreads

ENOMEM; winpthreads allocates mutexes on the stack, and if it can't allocate memory on the stack when the mutex is locked for the first time, this will fail. This is actually a case when std::mutex::lock() could genuinely fail for you if the system is completely out of memory. (Or at least your process is out of virtual memory if e.g. on 32bit.)
EDEADLK if you attempt to lock a non-recursive mutex you already hold the lock to. This will not happen in your case.
EPERM; winpthreads uses a WinApi Event object internally for notifications, if it cannot create that due to permissions, this will fail. This is actually a case when std::mutex::lock() could genuinely fail for you.
ENOMEM; if winpthreads cannot create the WinApi Event object because the system is out of resources (e.g. cannot create the event handle). This is actually a case when std::mutex::lock() could genuinely fail for you.
EINVAL if the mutex was not properly initialized. This will not happen in your case.

(See the mutex.cpp of winpthreads for the source code.)
pthread_mutex_unlock() failures with winpthreads

ENOMEM in the case of error-checking mutexes. This will not happen in your case.
EINVAL if pthread_mutex_unlock() is called on an unlocked mutex. This will not happen in your case.
EPERM if you try to unlock a mutex that is not owned by the current thread. This will not happen in your case.
EPERM if WinApi's SetEvent() fails due to permission errors. This is actually a case when std::mutex::unlock() could genuinely fail for you.

_MCF_mutex_lock() failures with mcfgthread

This appears to be implemented in such a manner that it cannot fail.

(See mcfgthread's mutex.c source code for details. Only timed mutexes might return -1.)
_MCF_mutex_unlock() failures with mcfgthread

This is implemented in such a manner that it cannot fail.

Summary
After having looked at all of the major implementations of std::mutex, the way your second example using std::mutex is written is such that you can easily mark the getCopy() and setValue() methods noexcept without any downsides, because they will in fact not actually throw in practice for your usage of std::mutex and std::lock_guard.
The only exception is MinGW/GCC with winpthreads as the backend, because that apparently implemented its mutex with heap allocations and event objects that require the kernel to allocate handles, which obviously can fail.
That said, you could always use a custom mutex implementation such as this one that uses SRWLock on Windows (regardless of MSVC/MinGW) and pthread_mutex on all other systems:
#if defined(_WIN32)
#include <windows.h>
#else
#include <pthread.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#endif

#include <exception>
#include <system_error>
#include <iostream>

class custom_mutex
{
public:
#if defined(_WIN32)
    using native_handle_type = PSRWLOCK;
#else
    using native_handle_type = pthread_mutex_t*;
#endif

    constexpr inline custom_mutex() noexcept
    {
    }

    inline ~custom_mutex() noexcept
    {
#if defined(_WIN32)
        // Do nothing, there is no DeleteSRWLock function
#else
        int r = pthread_mutex_destroy(&m_mutex);
        if (r == EBUSY) {
            /* We are trying to destroy a locked mutex, this means the
             * program is in an invalid state.
             */
            std::terminate();
        }
#endif
    }

    custom_mutex(custom_mutex const&) = delete;
    custom_mutex& operator=(custom_mutex const&) = delete;

    inline void lock()
    {
#if defined(_WIN32)
        AcquireSRWLockExclusive(&m_srwLock);
#else
        int r = pthread_mutex_lock(&m_mutex);
        if (r != 0)
            throw std::system_error(r, std::system_category(), strerror(r));
#endif
    }

    inline bool try_lock()
    {
#if defined(_WIN32)
        return TryAcquireSRWLockExclusive(&m_srwLock);
#else
        int r = pthread_mutex_trylock(&m_mutex);
        if (r != 0) {
            if (r == EBUSY)
                return false;
            throw std::system_error(r, std::system_category(), strerror(r));
        }
        return true;
#endif
    }

    void unlock()
    {
#if defined(_WIN32)
        ReleaseSRWLockExclusive(&m_srwLock);
#else
        int r = pthread_mutex_unlock(&m_mutex);
        if (r != 0)
            throw std::system_error(r, std::system_category(), strerror(r));
#endif
    }

    inline native_handle_type native_handle()
    {
#if defined(_WIN32)
        return &m_srwLock;
#else
        return &m_mutex;
#endif
    }

private:
#if defined(_WIN32)
    SRWLOCK m_srwLock = SRWLOCK_INIT;
#else
    pthread_mutex_t m_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
#endif
};

While this implementation of a mutex can technically still throw in lock() and unlock(), it will not do that in your specific usage of that class, because of the discussion how pthread_mutex_lock() and pthread_mutex_unlock() actually react. Also, in the Windows case it doesn't do any error checking at all, so technically doesn't fulfill the contract of std::mutex (which is why Microsoft's STL has the deadlock check in lock() in addition to the call to AcquireSRWLockExclusive()).
